# Can I force flushing a CAN bus socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, can-bus

in my software (written in C++) I'm using the Linux standard functions to open and do I/O stuff on a CAN bus socket.

The socket is opened and used as following:

```
   /* Create the socket */
if ((skt = socket( PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW )) < 0)
{
  ...
}

struct ifreq ifr;
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "can0");
ioctl(skt, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);

struct sockaddr_can addr;
addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

ifr.ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue = 1000000/2;
ioctl(skt, SIOCSCANBAUDRATE, &ifr);

if(bind( skt, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr) ) < 0)
{
  ...
}
```

Later on the code...

```
write(skt, &msg, sizeof(struct can_frame));
```

However I noticed that sometimes the messages I've just wrote on the socket aren't sended over the bus.
I thought it's like a buffer who needs an explicit flush sometimes (like a lot of messages at the same time etc).
I've searched around the Net but I've found nothing suitable for my case (many suggest to use fflush(), but I've got only the file descriptor declared as int), so the question is: there is a way to force the flush of a socket without using a FSTREAM?

Maybe isn't a problem which can be fixed from my software, but it's worth a try...

Comment: Try using sendto with the flag set to MSG_NOWAIT.  write is the same as send with no flags.

Comment: Use the [mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-can) to find help.

Comment: Are you checking, if write() was successful? It can be, that the buffer is full and you get `errno == ENOBUFS`.

Comment: @cup using send() and that flag isn't working, the problem persist.

Comment: @yegorich yes I check the number of bytes written, write() returns always the correct size

Comment: In that case, try fsync(skt)

Comment: @cup same thing... Now I'm going to check better for the errno status. I've tried to add a simple sleep of 100 ms after writing of 16 can_frame and the problem seems solved

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, incorrect bus termination can create all sorts of intermittent issues!

Perhaps try (if you haven't already):

- Check that you have 120 Ohm termination at both ends of your bus and that the terminating resistors are at (or close as possible to) the ends of the bus.
- Check the bus resistance: You should have 60 Ohms (+/- resistor tolerances) across the bus.

Answer (score -1):

Try using fflush or flushall and see it helps.

Comment: How can I use fflush() if it requires a FStream and I've got an int?
I don't think I can open a stream on the socket without causing serious problems...

Comment: Maybe this can help a little- http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?380878-How-to-run-a-very-long-SQL-statement

Comment: Those are STDIO methods that flush the buffer maintained  by STDIO. Nothing do so with it whatsoever.